# Average minimum distance between n points on a sphere.

Tags: probability

Consider $n$ points chosen uniformly and independently on the surface of a sphere with circumference  $1$ at the equator. What is the expected minimum (great-circle) distance between any pair of points?

If we considered a circle instead the answer would be $1/n^2$.

Comment: well there are $\lceil{n-2\over 2}\rceil+2 $ points in a hemisphere....

Comment: A sphere doesn't have a circumference.

Comment: @joriki https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-solids/sphere.php. What is the correct term?

Comment: OK, I reopened due to the difference. However, note that the asymptotics will be the same and a closed-form solution is similarly unlikely, so the answers will probably not differ.

Comment: I'd call it the circumference of (or perhaps at) the equator, or generally the circumference of the great circles of the sphere.